# Phonegap javascript File saving

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile, filewriter

I am trying to save a simple text "Hello", into a file using the phonegap filewriter API. I checked the online docs together with some books(20 recipes for phonegap), however it is still giving me an error alert. The following is my code:

```
function SavetoFile(name, surname, mobilenumber, email, language, addressline1, addressline2, locality){

var fileWriter;

saveFile();

function onLoad(){
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSComplete, fail);            
}

function onFSComplete(fileSystem){ // load file, create it if it doesn't exist
    fileSystem.root.getFile("userdetails.txt", {create:true}. onFileEntryComplete, fail);   
}

function onFileEntryComplete(fileEntry){ // set up a file writer
    fileEntry.createWriter(onFileWriterComplete, fail); 
}

function onFileWriterComplete(fileWriter){ // store the file writer in a global variable for when user presses save
    fileWriter = fileWriter;        
}

function saveFile(){

    if(fileWriter != null){
        fileWriter.onwrite = function(evt){
            alert("Details Saved Successfully");                
        }

        var fileline = "Hello";
        fileWriter.write(fileline);

    }
    else{
        alert("There was an error trying to save the file");    
    }
    return false;

}

function fail(error) {
    alert(error.code);
    }
```

}

I am calling the main function **SavetoFile()** and passing the different parameters. However before making use of them, I wanted to test on a smaller scale just by saving the word "Hello" and thus I call another method **saveFile()** within the main function. This is still giving me an error message. Any idea what the source of the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

take care when call function SavetoFile.
Call it after load the document, using

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready',SavetoFile,false);
```

that is, do that in order to call SavetoFile function